# how to solve problem webview to play audio

Tags: android, webview

i use my site in `WebView` to create app of my site.
my site has one section to play sounds from other site.
my site is `https` and other site is `http` .when want play the song get this error from android studio

```
    E/EGL_emulation: eglQueryContext 32c0  EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
E/EGL_emulation: tid 3170: eglQueryContext(1456): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mysiteurl' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure video 'http://othersiteurl'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.", source: https://mysiteurl (0)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) NotSupportedError: Failed to load because no supported source was found.", source: undefined (0)
```

how i can solve this problem

Comment: Did you enabled javascript for webview?

Comment: yes, java script is enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must add

`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

to application tage in AndroidManifest.xml
and add

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        mWebView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode( WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW );
}
```

into OnCreate Your Activity

Comment: Works on My App. Thank you